# Include null field values in Jersey REST Response

Tags: rest, jersey

I'm including Instance of Following class in one of my REST Resource Response.

```
public class GenericResponse<T> implements Serializable {
    private String message;

    private String errorMessage;

    private String errorCode = "0";

    ....
}
```

There are other fields in this class but, when a field is null or "0" (as a String), they are being omitted in the Client's Response.

How to include all fields in the Client's REST response even though they are null/empty/0

Additional Information:
Jersey Version: 2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this with the Annotation

```
@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)
```

on

```
GenericResponse
```